# MySQL Order of Operations For IN parameter

Tags: mysql, query-string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mysql or/and precedence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345569/mysql-or-and-precedence)

If I have a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM `users`
 WHERE 'gen'='0' OR `gen`='1' AND `id` IN ('405','406','407',...),
```

will it return the results from users where (gen='0' or gen='1') and (`id` IN (...), or some other result? if so, can i put parentheses around the clauses to separate?

thanks.

Comment: sorry - there should be an AND before the IN. assuming the AND, would it work?

Comment: Your query above will not evaluate your `AND ID IN` condition if `gen=0`. Yes you can use parentheses and write your where clause like - `WHERE ('gen'='0' OR 'gen'='1') AND 'id' IN ('405','406','407',...)`

Comment: FWIW, When mixing OR and AND in the same statement I find it a lot easier to read if you explicitly put parentheses where you indent them to be, even if they are not truly necessary

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
SELECT * 
FROM `users`
WHERE `gen` IN (0, 1) AND 
      `id` IN ('405','406','407',...)
```

is the same as

```
SELECT * 
  FROM `users`
 WHERE (`gen`='0' OR `gen`='1') AND 
        `id` IN ('405','406','407',...)
```