# How `MySQL` define order in `WHERE` clause?

Tags: mysql, where-clause, logical-operators

Please, somebody explain me why queries:

```
WHERE property_id = 1 OR property_id = 2
    AND property_id = 3
```

and

```
WHERE (property_id = 1 OR property_id = 2)
    AND property_id = 3
```

given different results?

And how `MySQL` define order in `WHERE` clause?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql or/and precedence?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345569/mysql-or-and-precedence)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Programming_languages logical operators precedence is not specific to SQL

Comment: Err, because they are different queries?

Comment: @EJP the question is why they're two different queries. A lot of people would think these should produce the same results because they would be evaluated in order, not according to some precedence rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [Manual Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html) for Operator Precedence

In your first query where clause check this condition 
`property_id = 2 AND property_id = 3` because of `AND` operator is more precedence then `OR` Operator.

In second query where clause check first this condtion `(property_id = 1 OR property_id = 2)` because bracket have more precedence then other compare operator.

Your first query equivalent to

```
WHERE property_id = 1 OR (property_id = 2
    AND property_id = 3)
```

Comment: So if I don't use brackets, MySQL look up all AND operators and calc them, and then look up OR operators for calculation?

Comment: If  don't use brackets then first evaluate `AND` operator after that evaluate `OR` operator because `AND` operator is more precedence than `OR` operator

Answer (score 3):

Because of the precedence of the AND/OR logical operators

The first query is equivalent to

```
WHERE property_id = 1 OR (property_id = 2
    AND property_id = 3)
```

Because AND has higher precedence than OR operator

Comment: So MySQL look up all `AND` operators and calc them, and then look up `OR` operators for calculation?

Comment: Yeap, pretty much this

Comment: @Victor: Yes. Read MySQL documentation at [*Operator Precedence*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/operator-precedence.html)