# Use "or" and "and" correctly to select

Tags: mysql

I have a problem of connecting "and" and "or" together. 
Here's my code:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE '$name'  
  AND color LIKE '$color' 
  OR color2 LIKE '$color2' 
  OR color3 LIKE '$color3' 
  AND gender  LIKE '$gender'  -- when I add those 3, search stops working.
  OR gender2 LIKE '$gender2' 
  OR gender3 LIKE '$gender3'
```

The problem is that when I add "gender" to select, my search stops working... Is there a problem with double "or"   or maybe with the positioning?

Comment: Make proper use of parenthesis. Its like doing algebra, you have to put the parenthesis around stuff that goes together.

Comment: use parenthesis to group statements

Comment: Can't you pick _one_ technology?

Comment: The MySQL **`AND`** and **`OR`** operators have an **order of precedence**. That means those operators get evaluated in a specific order. It's likely that this differs from the order you expected. You can explicitly specify the sequence of operations by using parentheses. (The operations within parentheses are evaluated first.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use parentheses to separate your ORs and ANDs into the proper groups. Some additional formatting of the SQL will make it more obvious what your intentions are:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    table 
WHERE 
    name LIKE '$name'  
    AND 
    (
        color LIKE '$color' 
        OR 
        color2 LIKE '$color2' 
        OR 
        color3 LIKE '$color3'
    ) 
    AND 
    (
        gender LIKE '$gender'
        OR 
        gender2 LIKE '$gender2' 
        OR 
        gender3 LIKE '$gender3'
    )
```

Lastly, you're not using any wildcards in your `LIKE` expressions. I would suggest simply using `=` instead, as it will be faster.

I would suggest reading through the following MySQL reference documentation to get a clearer picture on why this works the way it does:

- [12.3.1 Operator Precedence](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html)

Or this Q/A here:

- [Mysql or/and precedence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345569/mysql-or-and-precedence)

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. I will look into this tomorrow. And if it works, I will tick it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using parenthesis to make things more obvious.

You should have a look into Operator Precedence (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html) to see what statement will be evaluated first, second, etc. Parenthesis make this much more explicit.

I was going to post fixed SQL, but Cory has already done it above