# How do I add WHERE hide != 1 to my select statement?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM system_passwords 
    WHERE hide != 1 AND (`id` LIKE '%".$query."%') 
    OR (`system_name` LIKE '%".$query."%') 
    OR (`database_name` LIKE '%".$query."%') 
    OR (`username` LIKE '%".$query."%') 
    OR (`password` LIKE '%".$query."%') 
    OR (`notes` LIKE '%".$query."%') 
    OR (`additional_info` LIKE '%".$query."%')") or die(mysql_error());
```

How or where do I add hide != 1  into this?

Comment: It's already there, what is the question exactly?

Comment: It doesn't work where it is so I was asking where it should go, or how to write it.

Comment: Doesn't work as in you get an error or it doesn't give you the results you expect?

Comment: It doesn't ignore the rows with entries in column "hide" with value 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to group the `or`s together. As is your query runs as

```
WHERE hide != 1 AND (`id` LIKE '%".$query."%')
```

or

```
(system_name LIKE '%".$query."%')
```

or etc.

This should group the values as you expect.

```
SELECT * FROM system_passwords 
WHERE (
        (`id` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR 
        (`system_name` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR 
        (`database_name` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR 
        (`username` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR 
        (`password` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR 
        (`notes` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR 
        (`additional_info` LIKE '%".$query."%')
    ) and hide != 1
```

You also should switch over to `PDO` or `mysqli` so you can use prepared statements. This may open you to SQL injections; not knowing what `$query` can't say for certain..

Additional information: [Mysql or/and precedence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345569/mysql-or-and-precedence)

Answer (score 1):

It is in the right place, but this is less ambiguous logically
`WHERE hide != 1 AND ([a] OR [b] OR [c])`