# MySQL: return posts if meta_key does NOT exist

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, metadata, meta-key

I have a query that returns a pet post if the meta_key exists and is not '':

```
-- Pets that are assigned tags
SELECT p.ID
FROM FxFfekP0_posts p LEFT JOIN FxFfekP0_postmeta pm
ON p.ID = pm.post_id
WHERE p.post_type = 'pets'
AND pm.meta_key = 'tag'
AND pm.meta_value != ''
```

But now I need to get a result set that contains posts that either do not contain the meta_key `tag` at all, or the meta_key `tag` = '' ...

Help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT p.ID
FROM FxFfekP0_posts p LEFT JOIN FxFfekP0_postmeta pm
ON p.ID = pm.post_id AND pm.meta_key = 'tag'
WHERE p.post_type = 'pets'
AND ifnull(pm.meta_value, '') = ''
```

I've moved the `pm.meta_key = 'tag'` into the join condition, so missing rows still appear in the result set (as `NULL`s); the `ifnull()` then allows a single condition to pick up both `NULL`s and empty strings.

Comment: If I've explained moving the condition into the join badly, just compare `SELECT p.ID FROM FxFfekP0_posts p LEFT JOIN FxFfekP0_postmeta pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id WHERE p.post_type = 'pets' AND pm.meta_key = 'tag'` with `SELECT p.ID FROM FxFfekP0_posts p LEFT JOIN FxFfekP0_postmeta pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id AND pm.meta_key = 'tag' WHERE p.post_type = 'post'`.  The latter should return a lot more rows, importantly including those posts with no tag entries in the postmeta table

Comment: I basically need to separate the two. I need to know which Pets have a Tag (where tag exists and is not blank or NULL) ... and then know which Pets don't have a tag (no value at all), or the tag entry is blank.

Comment: I'm a little lost.  You have the first query (you posted it in the question); this query returns the second result set (which is what you specifically asked for) - posts whose tags are missing or blank.  Unless it didn't work for you because I had the post type wrong from my testing (now corrected)?

Comment: Yeah, it didn't initially work. But your updated query seems to be working now. I wish I could fully understand what you've done there... I've never seen the `ifnull()` before.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will work for what I'm looking for ... unless someone can point out where this query fails:

```
SELECT p.ID
FROM FxFfekP0_posts p
LEFT JOIN FxFfekP0_postmeta pm ON pm.post_id = p.ID 
AND pm.meta_key = 'tag'
WHERE p.post_type = 'pets'
AND pm.meta_key IS NULL 
OR pm.meta_value = ''
```

Comment: I'd be a little careful with the precedence of `AND` and `OR`.  While it may be unlikely in your particular case, if you have a difference post type with a "tag" meta key, you could get unexpected results.  MySQL will interpret your `where` clause as `WHERE ( p.post_type = 'pets' AND pm.meta_key IS NULL ) OR ( pm.meta_value = '' )`.  I'd put parentheses around `pm.meta_key IS NULL  OR pm.meta_value = ''`.  Other than that, isn't this logically the same as my answer?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345569/mysql-or-and-precedence for more detail