# MySQL multiple column search return wrong result

Tags: mysql, search, conditional-statements, multiple-columns

I have below conditional query to perform multiple columns searches

```
SELECT 
    prod.pid, 
    prod.pname, 
    prod.description, 
    prod.status, 
    foto.set_cover, 
    foto.filename
FROM products prod
INNER JOIN second_child_categories secd ON prod.category_id = secd.second_id
INNER JOIN photos foto ON prod.pid = foto.pid
WHERE CONCAT( prod.pname, prod.description ) LIKE '%home%'
OR CONCAT( prod.description, prod.pname ) LIKE '%home%'
AND foto.set_cover = '1'
AND prod.status = '1'
ORDER BY prod.created_date DESC
```

Here's the output:

[image]

As refer to query, I set conditions:

```
foto.set_cover='1' AND prod.status='1'
```

the results are not matches with the condition.

How can I fix this query?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Mysql or/and precedence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345569/mysql-or-and-precedence#12345698)

`OR`has a higher precedence, what you (implicitly) wrote:

```
CONCAT( prod.pname, prod.description ) LIKE '%home%'
OR (
  CONCAT( prod.description, prod.pname ) LIKE '%home%'
  AND foto.set_cover = '1'
  AND prod.status = '1'
)
```

what I think what you meant

```
( 
  CONCAT( prod.pname, prod.description ) LIKE '%home%'
  OR 
  CONCAT( prod.description, prod.pname ) LIKE '%home%'
)
AND foto.set_cover = '1'
AND prod.status = '1'
```