# WHERE clause return incorrect result

Tags: mysql, sql

I want return all the records that have as `team_id` a certain number and have a specific `round_id`, so I wrote this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `match` WHERE home_team_id = 68 OR away_team_id = 68 AND round_id = 70
```

this will return:

```
{
    "id": "61032",
    "round_id": "70",
    "home_team_id": "68",
    "away_team_id": "76",
},
{
    "id": "61052",
    "round_id": "75",
    "home_team_id": "68",
    "away_team_id": "74",
},
```

why I get also the record with `round_id` = 75?

Comment: `WHERE (home_team_id = 68 OR away_team_id = 68) AND round_id = 70`

Comment: Try to avoid `OR` conditions - `WHERE 68 IN (home_team_id, away_team_id)  AND round_id = 70`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345569/mysql-or-and-precedence

Comment: @Alex could you explain why without the brackets it won't work?

Comment: The order of precedence is: NOT-AND-OR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the logic you want is:

```
where 68 in (home_team_id, away_team_id) and round_id = 70
```

You can also fix your logic by adjusting the parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need some parentheses to group your logic statements:

```
SELECT * 
FROM match 
WHERE home_team_id = 68 
    OR (
        away_team_id = 68 
        AND 
        round_id = 70
        )
```