# SQL execution order in where clause with and/or

Tags: sql

Does the SQL query

```
SELECT * FROM table_a where cond1 or cond2 and cond3;
```

deliver the same result as

```
SELECT * FROM table_a where (cond1 or cond2) and cond3;
```

?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql or/and precedence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345569/mysql-or-and-precedence)

Comment: No, they will be different because without the () the AND will go first

Comment: Have you tried to run a query with both sets of logic and see if they differ?  You can answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

No.  Boolean operators have precedence rules -- in all programming languages that use them and in mathematics before that.  "AND" binds more closely than "OR".  This is analogous to arithmetic operators.

Just as:

```
1 + 2 * 3
```

is different from:

```
(1 + 2) * 3
```

Your two versions are different.  `AND` binds more tightly (like `*`).  `OR` less tightly (like `+`).