# Why does mySQL query give unexpected results?

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my mySQL query :

```
SELECT mCat,postSta 
FROM `info_posts` 
WHERE `mCat` = 'Mobiles' AND `sCat` = 'Mobile Phones' AND `brCat` = 'Apple' AND `postSta` = 1 OR `postSta` = 4 OR `postSta` = 5
```

The problem with this is that it selects all the criteria properly however it also fetches the things where postSta = 4 and 5 [take a look at the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQslF.png). I want to select things which match the criteria of mCat,sCat and brCat where postSta is 1 or 4 or 5.

Comment: The problem is in the way the AND and OR conditions are being processed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql or/and precedence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345569/mysql-or-and-precedence)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logical "and" operation has a higher precedence than the logical "or" operator. The logic you're looking for can be achieved by surrounding the series of "or" conditions with parenthesis:

```
SELECT `mCat`, `postSta`
FROM   `info_posts`
WHERE  `mCat` = 'Mobiles' AND
       `sCat` = 'Mobile Phones' AND
       `brCat` = 'Apple' AND
       (`postSta` = 1 OR `postSta` = 4 OR `postSta` = 5)
```

Comment: Thanks buddy !! That helped

Answer (score 3):

Use `IN`:

```
SELECT mCat,postSta
FROM info_posts
WHERE mCat = 'Mobiles' AND sCat = 'Mobile Phones' AND brCat = 'Apple' AND 
      postSta IN (1, 4, 5)
```

The problem is that you need parentheses in your query, but `IN` is a better approach.

Comment: Thanks buddy !! That helped