# Issue with Case Condition in My SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have  a  sample  table where I have written Case statement.
where I'm not able  to write  the  proper syntax.

```sql
SELECT 
    case
        when SECTION = 'A' then
            case
                WHEN (SECTION ='A' AND ROLE = ROLENUMBER) 
                THEN 'GOOD' 
                ELSE 'BAD'
            end
        else 
            case
                when SECTION <> 'A' and ROLE <> 0 and ROLE is not null and ROLENUMBER <> 0 and ROLENUMBER <> null and ROLENUMBER <> ROLE 
                    then 'GOOD' 
                    else  'BAD'  
            when SECTION <> 'A' and (ROLE = 0 or   ROLE IS null) and ROLENUMBER = ROLE 
                then 'GOOD' 
                else  'BAD'  
        end
FROM
    CLASSROOM
```

Apart from Case Condition is  there anyother  way to write like IF condition with in the Case condition.

I'm looking  to write query like `IF section = 'A' then execute 1st condition ELSE IF section <> 'A'then execute  below condition`.

Comment: You don't need to repeat `SECTION='A'` in the nested `CASE`.

Comment: You can't use `!=` with `NULL`. You have to write `ROLE IS NOT NULL`

Comment: At least one problem in your code is you're using `!= null` - which won't work in SQL, because in SQL a `NULL` cannot be compared to anything, even itself, i.e.: `( NULL != NULL ) => FALSE` and `( NULL == NULL ) => FALSE` - you have to use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` instead.

Comment: You're missing an `END` for one of your `CASE` keywords.

Comment: The `ELSE CASE` probably doesn't need a nested case. Just make them two more `WHEN` clauses for the original `CASE`. And you don't need `SECTION != 'A'` since that's already handled by the first `WHEN`.

Comment: thanks  @Barmar for  suggestions . I'm getting syntax errors. Can you suggest in answer section

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out the logic you're trying to implement. Can you explain all the "good" conditions?

Comment: section = 'A' then 1st  condition else  need  to execute second  condition @Barmar I want to eliminate  syntax errors

Comment: You can fix syntax errors just by making sure that every `CASE` has a matching `END`. Whether it will do what you actually want is a different problem.

Comment: You can also use the simpler `IF(condition, truevalue, falsevalue)` expression, e.g. `IF(ROLE = ROLENUMBER, 'GOOD', 'BAD')`

Comment: and you can have multiple `WHEN` uses, but only one `ELSE` in a `CASE.....END`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this capture all your "good" conditions?

```
  case 
     when section = 'A' and role = rolenumber then 'good'
     when section <> 'A' and role <> 0 and role is not null 
       and rolenumber <> 0  and rolenumber <> null and rolenumber <> role then 'good'
     when section <> 'A' and (role = 0 or role is null) and rolenumber = role then 'good'
     else 'bad'
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write it more simpler like this.

```
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN SECTION = 'A' AND ROLE = 'ROLENUMBER' THEN 'GOOD'
        WHEN
            SECTION != 'A' AND ROLE  0
                AND ROLE IS NOT NULL
                AND ROLENUMBER  0
                AND ROLENUMBER  NULL
                AND ROLENUMBER  ROLE
        THEN
            'GOOD'
        WHEN
            SECTION != 'A' AND ROLE = 0
                OR ROLE IS NULL AND ROLENUMBER = ROLE
        THEN
            'GOOD'
        ELSE 'BAD'
    END
FROM
    CLASSROOM
```

Comment: No, because when will this be true? `ROLE IS NULL AND ROLENUMBER = ROLE`  ==> Never, because when ROLE IS NULL it will never be equal to ROLENUMBER  (and  `AND` has a higher precedence than `OR` , see: [Mysql or/and precedence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345569/mysql-or-and-precedence))